# Where are my promela syntax errors?

Tags: spin, promela

I seem to be too stupid to see it. The log shows me where my syntax errors are (line 12, 22 and 25), I read some tutorials, but cannot find the errors..

The program is very simple, it should count the amount of 0's and 1's through a synchronized channel.

Here is my code:

```
1   
2   chan ch = [0] of {bool};
3   byte zero, one;
4   bool message;
5   
6   proctype A() {
7   startA: 
8   if
9   :: ch ! 0
10  :: ch ! 1
11  fi
12  goto startA
13  }
14  
15  proctype B() {
16  startB:
17  ch ? message;
18  if
19  :: message -> one++
20  :: ! message -> zero++
21  fi
22  goto startB
23  }
24  
25  init { atomic {run A(); run B()} }
```

And my syntax errors:

```
spin: firstchannel.pml:12, Error: syntax error  saw 'keyword: goto' near 'goto'
spin: firstchannel.pml:22, Error: syntax error  saw 'keyword: goto' near 'goto'
spin: firstchannel.pml:25, Error: proctype A not found
```

I'd be happy for a tip..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I need semicolons after the if statements.